# Why did Tokyo Jungle just exit mid game?

Tags: playstation-plus, tokyo-jungle

I was playing *Tokyo Jungle* and while playing it i was getting a console message at the top corner saying that

> This content will expire in # Minutes

i first got it just after i did the tutorial saying 30 minutes, then 15, 10, 5 and all of a sudden while i was playing the main game the game just exited and put be strait back to the PS3 Dashboard. When i went back into the game there was no progressed saved.

I know what i downloaded wasn't a trail because games like *From Dust* and *Raymen 3* where It lists a trail download and a much much smaller game download because *Tokyo Jungle* is listed as a PSN Game

[image: Download List]

and I got *Tokyo Jungle* from my PS+ Subscription (which is still active and i was logged in) and in the checkout it didn't list that it was a trail

[image: Receipt]
<sup><sup>as you can see the purchaser date in the download list is incorrect, i did not get it with my *Tales of Hearts* DLC which i did buy this year</sup></sup>

so since my game wasn't a trail, why did it exit like it did?

Comment: Was the PS3 connected to the internet when this happened? It sounds to me like your PS3 couldn't validate you PS+ subscription and it thinks it ran out. If you renewed on another device like a PS4 or the subscription auto-renewed but the PS3 wasn't connected to the the internet to see the subscription was renewed. I know on PS4 when you hit options/information on the game tile it tells you when/if it will expire. For free PS+ games this is a count down until your subscriptions expires, there might be a way to check if your PS3 thinks your PS+ is active in options.